# Using Storybook with Radix UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I'm using [Radix UI](https://www.radix-ui.com/) to build out my components (basically just styling their primitives and exporting them together). For example, I have this in my `Checkbox.tsx` file:

```
import { CheckIcon as StyledCheckIcon } from '@radix-ui/react-icons'
import * as CheckboxPrimitive from '@radix-ui/react-checkbox'
import { styled } from '@stitches/react'

const StyledContainer = styled('div', {
    ...
})

const StyledCheckbox = styled(CheckboxPrimitive.Root, {
    ...
})

const StyledIndicator = styled(CheckboxPrimitive.Indicator, {
    ...
})

const StyledLabel = styled('label', {
    ...
})

export const Container = StyledContainer
export const Root = StyledCheckbox
export const Indicator = StyledIndicator
export const CheckIcon = StyledCheckIcon
export const Label = StyledLabel
```

I can use this in `App.tsx` in the following way:

```
import * as Checkbox from "./components/Checkbox";

function App() {
  return (
    <Checkbox.Container>
      <Checkbox.Root id="c1" defaultChecked>
        <Checkbox.Indicator>
          <Checkbox.CheckIcon />
        </Checkbox.Indicator>
      </Checkbox.Root>
      <Checkbox.Label htmlFor="c1">
        Accept terms and conditions
      </Checkbox.Label>
    </Checkbox.Container>
  )
}
```

This works perfectly fine, however, when I want to actually create a story for this component, it gets a bit difficult (mainly because it's not really just a component, it's a composite). I can do the following in my `Checkbox.stories.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ComponentStory, ComponentMeta } from '@storybook/react';
import * as Checkbox from '../components/Checkbox';

const CheckboxComponent:any = function() {
  return (
    <Checkbox.Container>
      <Checkbox.Root id="c1" defaultChecked>
        <Checkbox.Indicator>
          <Checkbox.CheckIcon />
        </Checkbox.Indicator>
      </Checkbox.Root>
      <Checkbox.Label htmlFor="c1">
        Accept terms and conditions
      </Checkbox.Label>
    </Checkbox.Container>
  )
}

export default {
  title: 'Example/Checkbox',
  component: CheckboxComponent,
} as ComponentMeta<typeof CheckboxComponent>;

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof CheckboxComponent> = (args) => <CheckboxComponent {...args} />;

export const Default = Template.bind({});
```

This runs okay and the output is a checkbox, but I can't automatically control the props on the `Root` and the `Indicator` which are styled Radix primitives: [Checkbox docs from Radix](https://www.radix-ui.com/docs/primitives/components/checkbox#api-reference). How do I use Storybook with Radix components?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong you're passing `args` to `CheckboxComponent` but your function doesn't expect any arguments.

```
const CheckboxComponent:any = function() {
      return (...)
}
```

If you want to control it via storybook you have to handle it. I think this article should help you https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/introduction#using-args